# Solve $\left|\frac{2}{2+i-z}\right|<1$ being $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I have to solve the following inequation: $\space$

$\left|\frac{2}{2+i-z}\right|<1$ being $z\in \mathbb{C}$

---

This is what I have done: $\space$

$\left|\frac{2}{2+i-z}\right|<1 \to \frac{|2|}{|2+i-z|}<1 \to \frac{2}{|2+i-z|}<1 \to 2<|2+i-z|\le|2+i|+|-z| \to 2<|2+i|+|-z| \to 2<|2+i|+|z|$ $\space$

And we know that $|z|=d(z,0)$ and $|2+i|=d(2+i,0)=\sqrt{5}$ $\space$

So I obtain that $2<\sqrt{5}+d(z,0) \to d(z,0)>2-\sqrt{5}=-0.236...$ $\space$

But $d(z,0)$ is always positive so is that inequation always true? Or what I have done wrong? Could someone help me?

Comment: $d(z,0)>-0.2 \dots$ still allows the possibility that $d(z,0)$ is positive (and it is positive), so there is nothing wrong with your inequality

Comment: $|2+i-z| > 2$ implies $|2+i|+|-z| > 2$, but not the other way round. Hence the latter is always true, but not the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, by triangle inequality we obtain a correct result but it is not useful to solve the given problem.

To proceed, we have that

$$\left|\frac{2}{2+i-z}\right|<1 \iff |z-(2+i)|>2$$

which represents the region out of the circle centered at $2+i$ with radius $2$.